# How can I make button take the user to another page on click?

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink, dreamweaver

I have created a button on Dreamweaver,

Using Dreamweaver, How can I make button take the user to another page on click?

This is the link for the button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:window.location.assign("http://google.com");">
```

A more modern equivalent is:

```
<button onclick="javascript:window.location.assign("http://google.com");">
  Submit
</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a bad approach! It will work, but it is not good practice. Use `a` tags for links. Style the as buttons if need be but don't use a button and javascript. Buttons will not be activated by search engines, screen readers could struggle with them for visually impaired uses. Use the element that is made for this: `a`

Comment: Yes, this is true, but it also wasn't the question - the question was specifically related to using a form element.

Comment: You don't need `javascript:` for `onlick` attributes, that is for urls.